# IIS hosting vs Built In Web server that ships with VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, iis

I am looking to host a wcf service while i am developing.

Is this best with IIS or can i just use the default BUILT IN web server that ships with Visual Studio?

I can change the Assign automatic port to specific port so in my client i always ahave a fixed address.

I was hoping somebody could advise the best way to go?

Answer (score 2):

The most convenient way to host a WCF service during development is using the [WCF Service Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363.aspx) built into Visual Studio.

You can control the communication protocol and port used by your services in the [WCF configuration settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx):

```
<services>
    <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
        <endpoint 
            address="http://localhost:8080/myservice"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="MyNamespace.MyContract"  />
    </service>
</services>
```

However, if you need to run your services in the ASP.NET pipeline, I'll go with the [ASP.NET Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(VS.90).aspx) (formerly known as Cassini).